# Showing subcategory based on the main category does not work with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a car "make" and car "model" tables in my database. When I echo car "makes" it works properly. However, I want the car "model" drop-down to appear with ajax based on selected "make", it does not work in the view

[image]

However, all information that I need, appears on the console's network tab.

[image]

Where can be the problem? Here is my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="make"]').on('change', function() {
            var makeid = $(this).val();
            if(makeid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'myform/ajax/'+makeid,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="model"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="model"]').append('<option value="value.id">'+ 'value.title' +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="model"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php $attributes = array( 'name' => 'addcar', 'id' => 'addcar'); ?>
                  <?php echo form_open_multipart('cars/create', $attributes); ?>

                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Марка
                                    <small>*</small>
                                </label>
                                <select id="make" name="make" class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" required="true">
                                    <option value=""></option>

                                    <?php foreach($makes as $make): ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $make['id']; ?>"><?= $make['maketitle']; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                              </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Модель
                                    <small>*</small>
                                </label>
                                <select id="model" name="model" class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" required="true">

                              </select>
                            </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I can't see any name property in the response, all I can see is a title? On top of that, the append is not escaped properly. Like this you simply add strings (value.id, value.name). Since your selection is empty, did you verify that you are in the success condition at all?

Comment: Sorry, edited...

Comment: Still wrong it should be: '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ value.title + '</option>'

Comment: remove   $(document).ready(function()  , it makes it out of scope after page is loaded

Comment: @AhmedSunny the method binds an event to the select field, so there is no problem running this inside the ready function.

Comment: Nothing worked :(

Comment: give it id and call it by id

Comment: share your hmtl code too

Comment: The post has been edited

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to select element, but indeed you need to insert into it. Just get the first (option) element inside select and then append to that, something like this:

```
<select>
<option id="firstOption">First Option</option>
</select>


$("#firstOption").append(...)
```

And by the way, why value.title is inside quotes ?

```
+ 'value.title' +
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question. As I use "Creative Tim" admin dashboard, they have their own classes. And when I removed class="selectpicker" from the select part it worked. Actually, I don't know what is the connection between them?

Answer (score -1):

You're not writing your values correctly, and you need to match the properties from the objects in your response to what you're trying to output:

```
$('select[name="model"]').append('<option value="value.id">'+ 'value.title' +'</option>');
```

should be

```
$('select[name="model"]').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">'+ value.modeltitle +'</option>');
```